# Rails Nested form - validate how many files are uploaded on form for same model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a nested form with multiple file field for `:data`. As you see below,'n' number of `ApplicationFile` model records are created where `n=@company_templates.size`. So in browser, if `n=2` I see 2 upload buttons but how do I validate 'not nil' (either on model or DB side) if user has uploaded a file for each upload `file_field` button. Many thanks.

```
 <%= f.fields_for :application_files, @company_templates.size{ApplicationFile.new}, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |my_file| %>
  <%= my_file.file_field :data, label: " ", class: 'btn btn-file' %><% end %>
```

In fact, I've implemented not-nil condition for`:data` on the model side, but it bypasses it.

```
validates_presence_of :data, :allow_nil => false, :message => " - Please upload all required files for this job."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in a way I imposed this on user on form side, with the following as the model side validation didnot succeed maybe because it's a nested form.

`<%= f.file_field :data, required: true %>`